# wifi module keeps getting soft blocked after reboot

Tags: drivers, wireless, network-manager, rfkill

I'm using an Odroid XU4 with their USB WiFi module 4 and the official Odroid distro of Ubuntu 16.04.

If I type `sudo rfkill unblock wifi` into a terminal, everything works fine, but I intend this machine to run headless and untethered, so that isn't a solution.

I have also already tried adding the unblock command both as a service and to /etc/rc.local. Neither worked.

Some suspicious lines from syslog:

```
NetworkManager[678]: <info>  [1525808228.9431] rfkill0: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/platform/soc/12110000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0) (driver rt2800usb)
NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1525809316.1008] (wlan0): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1525809321.7019] manager: WiFi hardware radio set disabled
NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1525809321.7114] manager: WiFi now disabled by radio killswitch
```

As far as I know, the XU4 does not have a hardware switch to disable WiFi.

```
$ lsmod

Module                  Size  Used by
fuse                   86016  3
cpufreq_conservative    16384  0
cpufreq_userspace      16384  0
cpufreq_powersave      16384  0
rt2800usb              28672  0
rt2800lib              98304  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00usb              20480  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              45056  3 rt2800lib,rt2800usb,rt2x00usb
mac80211              618496  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb
cfg80211              479232  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
rfkill                 20480  3 cfg80211
spidev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
evdev                  24576  4
spi_s3c64xx            20480  0
gpio_keys              20480  0
uio_pdrv_genirq        16384  0
extcon_usb_gpio        16384  0
uio                    16384  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
exynos_gpiomem         16384  0
ipv6                  380928  46
usbhid                 45056  0

$ sudo lshw -class network
USB                       

  *-network:0      
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 7
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 00:1e:06:32:7c:fd
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.09.9 duplex=full ip=[snip] link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 8
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 70:f1:1c:03:b3:d1
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=4.14.35-128 firmware=0.29 ip=[snip] link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11

$ lsusb
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc. hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 413c:2105 Dell Computer Corp. Model L100 Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:5572 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5572 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 2):

I logged in with a monitor and keyboard and found that there was an "Enable WiFi" menu item unchecked in the GUI. Checking that menu item seems to have resolved the problem. It looks like I could have also done this on the command line with `nmcli r wifi on`, if anyone else stumbles upon this question in the future.